# Maven can't find classes after downloading dependencies

Tags: java, maven, aws-sdk

I am new to Maven and I am trying to write a small piece of Java code. I am including some packages. Maven seems to download everything I am expected to need but when it comes to compiling it fails saying it can't find a particular class. The errors further state that it can't find any of of my imports. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

This is my code:

```
package in.myscratchpad.app;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBClient;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder builder = AmazonDBClientBuilder.standard();
    }
}
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>in.myscratchpad.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>in.myscratchpad.app.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.60</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

These are the errors I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-app: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/ec2-user/projects/kinesisProducer1/my-app/src/main/java/in/myscratchpad/app/App.java:[3,21] package com.amazonaws does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ec2-user/projects/kinesisProducer1/my-app/src/main/java/in/myscratchpad/app/App.java:[4,21] package com.amazonaws does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ec2-user/projects/kinesisProducer1/my-app/src/main/java/in/myscratchpad/app/App.java:[5,26] package com.amazonaws.auth does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ec2-user/projects/kinesisProducer1/my-app/src/main/java/in/myscratchpad/app/App.java:[6,34] package com.amazonaws.auth.profile does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ec2-user/projects/kinesisProducer1/my-app/src/main/java/in/myscratchpad/app/App.java:[7,29] package com.amazonaws.regions does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ec2-user/projects/kinesisProducer1/my-app/src/main/java/in/myscratchpad/app/App.java:[8,29] package com.amazonaws.regions does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ec2-user/projects/kinesisProducer1/my-app/src/main/java/in/myscratchpad/app/App.java:[9,39] package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ec2-user/projects/kinesisProducer1/my-app/src/main/java/in/myscratchpad/app/App.java:[20,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
[ERROR] location: class in.myscratchpad.app.App
[ERROR] /home/ec2-user/projects/kinesisProducer1/my-app/src/main/java/in/myscratchpad/app/App.java:[20,47] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable AmazonDBClientBuilder
[ERROR] location: class in.myscratchpad.app.App
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

When I simple keep the Hello, World code without the AWS packages it works fine, when I try to build the service client I get these errors.

Comment: In your pom.xml maybe `<type>pom</type>` should be `<type>jar</type>`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Or just omit the `<type>` tag entirely, the default is JAR.

Comment: _<type>pom</type_ and _<scope>import</scope>_ are only useful in _<dependencyManagement>_ section for defining default versions an scope for dependencies declared in the _<dependencies>_ section.

Answer (score 0):

It says

```
...cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable AmazonDBClientBuilder
[ERROR] location: class in.myscratchpad.app.App
```

Which seams to explain clearly that it can compile `in.myscratchpad.app.App` because there is a symbol in it (namely `AmazonDBClientBuilder`) which can not be found!

I don't know what this class is for but given that

- you do not have import for `AmazonDBClientBuilder` class
- you assign the result to `AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder` type

isn't that a typo in your code and you should use `AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()` instead?